# Correct answer for 4x4 determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm going through the exercises in Georgi E Shilov's Linear Algebra book and am on chapter 1 problem 2: "Write down all the terms appearing in the determinant of order four which have a minus sign and contain $ a_{23}$"

the answers I have arrived at are:

$a_{11}$$a_{23}$$a_{32}$$a_{44}$

$a_{12}$$a_{23}$$a_{34}$$a_{41}$

$a_{14}$$a_{23}$$a_{31}$$a_{42}$

The answers listed in the back of the book are the same except for this one below:

$a_{44}$$a_{23}$$a_{31}$$a_{42}$

Is that a typo with $a_{44}$?

Comment: Yes. It should be $a_{14}$.

Comment: thank you @CatalinZara I've lost trust in the answer key :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix of the form

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}\end{array}\right)
$$

the determinant is

\begin{eqnarray}
\det A &=& a_{14} a_{23} a_{32} a_{41} - a_{13} a_{24} a_{32} a_{41} - a_{14} a_{22} a_{33} a_{41} + a_{12} a_{24} a_{33} a_{41}\\
&+& a_{13} a_{22} a_{34} a_{41} - a_{12} a_{23} a_{34} a_{41} - a_{14} a_{23} a_{31} a_{42} + a_{13} a_{24} a_{31} a_{42} \\
&+& a_{14} a_{21} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{11} a_{24} a_{33} a_{42} - a_{13} a_{21} a_{34} a_{42} + a_{11} a_{23} a_{34} a_{42} \\
&+& a_{14} a_{22} a_{31} a_{43} - a_{12} a_{24} a_{31} a_{43} - a_{14} a_{21} a_{32} a_{43} + a_{11} a_{24} a_{32} a_{43} \\
&+& a_{12} a_{21} a_{34} a_{43} - a_{11} a_{22} a_{34} a_{43} - a_{13} a_{22} a_{31} a_{44} + a_{12} a_{23} a_{31} a_{44} \\
&+& a_{13} a_{21} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{11} a_{23} a_{32} a_{44} - a_{12} a_{21} a_{33} a_{44} + a_{11} a_{22} a_{33} a_{44}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: you have two 3 indexed rows

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's a typo. The answer should be $a_{14}a_{23}a_{31}a_{42}$ as none of the numbers can appear more than once as a row index. And also, $(4,3,1,2)$ is an odd permutation. So, the sign will be negative.